# How to redact possible phone number in string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-dlp

I am use Google Cloud DLP (node.js) for redact phone number from string (this string can contain other word). https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/samples/dlp-inspect-phone-number
For example I want redact phone number in: `Do transaction over phone to bypass fee. My number: 18776967786`

But Cloud DLP only redact phone number with international format. For example `+1-877-696-7786`

Anyone know good method for iterate through string and redact possible phone number?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, US_TOLLFREE_PHONE_NUMBER works as the infotype.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply! But what about other number not from US?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Jordanna Chord, **US_TOLLFREE_PHONE_NUMBER** works as infotype for given example. And for phone numbers other than US, you can use **PHONE_NUMBER** as infotype.

Specifying redactConfig redacts a given value by removing it completely. The redactConfig message has no arguments; specifying it enables its transformation. Refer [redactConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data#redactconfig) for more information.

Redact a given value. For example, if used with an [InfoTypeTransformation](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.deidentifyTemplates#infotypetransformation) transforming **PHONE_NUMBER**, and input 'My phone number is 206-555-0123', the output would be 'My phone number is '. You can specify one or more infoType transformations per request. Within each InfoTypeTransformation object, you specify both of the following:

- One or more [infoTypes](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference) to which a transformation should be applied (the infoTypes[] array object).
- A primitive transformation (the [PrimitiveTransformation](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.deidentifyTemplates#primitivetransformation) object).

The challenge here is that if there's no context and no formatting, then a phone number may just look like a ~10 digit number. If you want to redact phone numbers you should mention the correct format. Or else, turn on redaction of **PHONE_NUMBER** and **GENERIC_ID** with a threshold of UNLIKELY to remove even if it is not mentioned in the format.

**Example formats:**

| Item | Result | [Likelihood](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/InspectConfig#likelihood) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18776967786 | GENERIC_ID | UNLIKELY |
| 877-696-7786 | PHONE NUMBER | POSSIBLE |
| 877 696 7786 | PHONE NUMBER | POSSIBLE |
| +1 877 696 7786 | PHONE NUMBER | POSSIBLE |
| +18776967786 | PHONE NUMBER | POSSIBLE |

Answer (score 0):

Without format or context you would need to turn on redaction of `PHONE_NUMBER` and `GENERIC_ID` with threshold of `UNLIKELY` [1](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/likelihood).